# Problem upgrading from ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I updated Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 successfully. But today (23rd April), when I tried to update from 15.10 to 16.04, it says my manager is up to date. Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I did not have that same problem.

What could be a solution though is to run the following command from Terminal:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

This should launch the update manager and enable the 16.04 update.